# Can I use Ubuntu font in my commercial software running on Windows CE?

Tags: license, ubuntu-font-family

I'm now making commercial software for Windows CE O/S, and I want to embed Ubuntu font to my software. The file format will be converted to my own format to speed up my software.

In this case, am I need to obtain some kind of license? Or do it freely with including license.txt files on my software ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ubuntu Font Licencing FAQ](http://font.ubuntu.com/ufl/FAQ.html) you can an will be able to use the Ubuntu font for your programs, even if not related directly to Ubuntu as long as you follow the license agreement.

[`From the license:`](http://font.ubuntu.com/ufl/ubuntu-font-licence-1.0.txt)

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
>   copy of the Font Software, to propagate the Font Software, subject to
>   the below conditions:
>
> 1. Each copy of the Font Software must contain the above copyright
>      notice and this licence. These can be included either as stand-alone
>      text files, human-readable headers or in the appropriate machine-
>      readable metadata fields within text or binary files as long as those
>      fields can be easily viewed by the user.
> 2. The font name complies with the following:
>      a) The Original Version must retain its name, unmodified.
>      b)  Modified Versions which are Substantially Changed must be renamed to
>      avoid use of the name of the Original Version or similar names entirely.
>      (c) Modified Versions which are not Substantially Changed must be
>      renamed to both (i) retain the name of the Original Version and (ii) add
>      additional naming elements to distinguish the Modified Version from the
>      Original Version. The name of such Modified Versions must be the name of
>      the Original Version, with "derivative X" where X represents the name of
>      the new work, appended to that name.
> 3. The name(s) of the Copyright Holder(s) and any contributor to the
>      Font Software shall not be used to promote, endorse or advertise any
>      Modified Version, except (i) as required by this licence, (ii) to
>      acknowledge the contribution(s) of the Copyright Holder(s) or (iii) with
>      their explicit written permission.
> 4. The Font Software, modified or unmodified, in part or in whole, must
>      be distributed entirely under this licence, and must not be distributed
>      under any other licence. The requirement for fonts to remain under this
>      licence does not affect any document created using the Font Software,
>      except any version of the Font Software extracted from a document
>      created using the Font Software may only be distributed under this
>      licence.